# How do I get stdin length from a pipe? echo "hello" | ./get_stdin_size

Tags: c, linux

I installed an application and its command line can do:

1. `command -input 1.txt`
2. `command < 1.txt`
3. `echo "hello" | command`

and output something. I don't have the source code and want to implement that behaviour too.

What I've tried is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    if ((fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END), ftell(stdin)) > 0){
        rewind(stdin);
        printf("stdin has data\n");
        char buffer[100];
        fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);
        printf("stdin data are: %s\n", buffer);
    }else{
        if (argc < 2){
            printf("no cmd arguments\n");
            return -1;
        }else{
            printf("command line argument: %s\n", argv[1]);
            FILE* fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
            if (fp == NULL){
                printf("NULL fp pointer\n");
                return -1;
            }
            char a[100] = {0};
            fgets(a, sizeof a, fp);
            printf("first line of file: %s\n", a);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But the problem is that **pipes** are not seekable. So `((fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END), ftell(stdin)) > 0)` doesn't fit all cases.

One solution that I think of is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    if (argc > 1){
        //open file with argv[1] as filename
        //read data from disk file
    }else{
        //read data from stdin
        if(stdin is file){
            //get file size
            //read data from stdin
        }else if(stdin is pipe){
            //get pipe size
            //read data from stdin
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have 2 problems with this code:

1. Is there a `ispipe()` function which works like `isatty(fileno(stdin))`? I need to tell if `stdin` is a `pipe`.
2. How do I get the `stdin` size/length from a pipe? Apparently I can't use:

```
    fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END);
    long size = ftell(stdin));
```

As @Peter pointed out in the comment, I should not try to get the stdin size from a pipe beforehand, then how do I know it reaches the end? Could anyone gives me an minimum example about this "stream-based processing"?

Comment: Well, the "size" is often factually unknowable: The pipe may be connected to a terminal and hits EOF when the user decides to press CTRL-d. Or the sending program decides at run time for some reason unknowable to the receiving program that now is the time to finish, or it is simply interrupted by the user. Even in the case of an input redirection from  file the file may be a special file, like `/dev/stdin`, or /dev/hda1`, or, worse, `/dev/zero`. Somebody may implement a `/dev/pi`!

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Then how would you like to implement it to make `echo "hello" | ./command` work? Preset a large buffer?

Comment: Perhaps the receiving end can, with OS dependent means, find out if it is reading from a pipe (or a socket, or something else). But it is sufficient to try to seek and see that it fails; we then know it is not a plain file. In that case there is no other way than to read to the end to find out. That can be surprisingly difficult. I think Sevens had something like a chapter devoted to it: Among other things, a `read` delivering less than the requested amount of data *does not* indicate EOF like with a file.

Comment: And yes, the problem is obviously that the data may be infinite (as with `/dev/zero` or a program streaming some sensor data). If you try to find out how much space you must allocate to hold the data, you simply can't: You have to change your algorithm to stream-based processing. Read chunks, do something with the data, read the next chunk (chunks are typically a page size, some power of 2). Typically you must have logic to combine logical data records which accidentally span the chunk gap... On top of that, be prepared to have short reads (less than requested).

Comment: *So `((fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END), ftell(stdin)) > 0)` doesn't fit all cases.*  Pedantically, it doesn't fit **ANY** case. In standard-conformant C code, you can't use `fseek()`/`ftell()` to get the size of a file. [`fseek(..., 0, SEEK_END)` on a binary stream is undefined behavior](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note268): "Setting the file position indicator to end-of-file, as with `fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END)`, has undefined behavior for a binary stream..."

Comment: (cont) [And `ftell()` on text streams doesn't provide a byte offset](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.9.4p2): "For a text stream, its file position indicator contains unspecified information, usable by the fseek function for returning the file position indicator for the stream to its position at the time of the ftell call; the difference between two such return values is not necessarily a meaningful measure of the number of characters written or read."

Comment: @AndrewHenle Wow that's too hard for me to understand. I retag the question to `Linux`.  Does that work well on Linux?

Comment: @Rick If you want to write reliable C or C++ code, you really do need to understand concepts like "undefined behavior" and "unspecified" at least enough to know how to read documentation well enough to avoid them.  It's all too easy to write unreliable or (even worse) insecure C or C++ code if you don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`fstat()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fstat.2.html) syscall to tell if standard input is a pipe (Either anonymous or named), or a file (And if a file, find its size):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
  struct stat s;

  if (fstat(STDIN_FILENO, &s) < 0) {
    perror("fstat");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  switch (s.st_mode & S_IFMT) {
  case S_IFIFO:
    puts("standard input is a pipe.");
    break;
  case S_IFREG:
    printf("standard input is a file that is %ld bytes in size.\n",
           (long)s.st_size);
    break;
  case S_IFCHR:
    if (isatty(STDIN_FILENO)) {
      puts("standard input is a terminal.");
    } else {
      puts("standard input is a character device.");
    }
    break;
  default:
    puts("standard input is something else.");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Example:

```
$ gcc testpipe.c
$ cat testpipe.c | ./a.out
standard input is a pipe.
$ ./a.out < testpipe.c    
standard input is a file that is 525 bytes in size.
$ ./a.out
standard input is a terminal.
```

Comment: What does a TTY return in `st_mode & S_IFMT` on Linux?  That's probably worth adding as it's likely a very common value for `STDIN_FILENO`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Good idea. Added that case.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to be sure that you won't recieve more data from a pipe is when it is closed (`SIGPIPE` signal).

Thus, as stated in comments, allocating/reading the right of memory is challenging with pipes, since they can be infinite (e.g. `/dev/random`). You have to make hypothesis or use extra data in order to handle the pipe.

Depending on your use case, these strategies can be one of:

1. Sending the data length at the beginning of the message. This can be like: `echo -e'\x05\x00\x00\x00Hello'|./myprog`. With that strategy, it is trivial to read the pipe but it requieres that you know the total size of the input before you start sending it.
2. Allocating and reading a limited amount of data/time. If you recieve than `PIPE_MAX_SIZE` bytes or you wait more than `TIMEOUT_PIPE`, close the pipe and  handle the possibly incomplete message.
3. Handle the message block by block. If your message follows a regular pattern, you can read it this way and handle blocks sequentially until you reach the end of the message. This also allows you to discard previous buffer to read unlimited amount of data that would not fit in memory.

Comment: How would you do this for `/dev/random`for instance?

Comment: I don't know what is `/dev/random`. An infinte random byte stream?

Comment: Yes. Try it with `cat /dev/random`. This is not the only case though. For instance `/dev/zero`and `/dev/urandom`are also infinite byte streams. I think you don't understand how pipe works. Don't forget that pipes are just a "connection" between two entities and can either 1) send data then be closed 2) send data undefinitely 3) Hang undefinitely. Until you wait indefinitely which is by definition impossible you can't know in which situation you are with an unknown pipe.
The conclusion is: you have to make hypothesis as stated in my message

Comment: Thank you I understand now. I just tried `cat /dev/random | ./myprogram` and it did hang. But I got nothing from `/dev/zero`, I am using Ubuntu.

Comment: Strace do not hang it just display zeor bytes that aren't displayed by your terminal; Try ` strace -e trace=read cat /dev/zero `!

Comment: Yes you are right. I saw something interesting with `strace`. Thank you again Maxime. :). Oh and in the end I would use `fread` and `feof` and assume users would not do things like that lol. That's good enough for me.